# use batch file to call another batch file from different comp

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to use batch file (for XP) to call another batch file from **different** computer? if yes, how identify the target computer? Is it by IP comp ID?

Comment: Add clarity. Where do you want this called batch file to run? on the client machine? or the remote machine?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from Sysinternals/Microsoft.

The computer name can be specified either by name (assuming name resolution works on the network) or IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use UNC naming?  As in

ThisComputer.bat

```
   @echo on
    dir *.whatever
    call \\ServerName\C$\YourFolder\OtherComputer.bat
```