# How to redirect echo from batch to network PC?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch to do multiple file operations, it will work on an unwatched PC without connected display or speakers.

In case an error occurs it will write an errorlog and beep, but is there any way to redirect this and make my working PC beep instead? Both PCs are in the same network.

```
if "%ok%"=="0" set errorid=Fehler in der Ordnerbezeichnung & ren "%~dp0export\%~1" "%~1___FEHLER" & echo %~1;%datetimed%;%datetimet%;%errorid%>>"errorlog_%datetimed%.csv" & for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do timeout /t 1 >nul && @echo (here comes "bel", stackoverflow doesn't accept the charakter...)
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a batch program on one computer tell another to beep?

Comment: Or - if this doesn't work - how to call another batch stored on the other computer from the first one

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to have the original batch file call another one on the other computer. You can do this with [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Take a  look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289127/use-batch-file-to-call-another-batch-file-from-different-comp) to see how.

(Already answered in another question on stackoverflow)

Comment: so seems psexec does the magic... 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Thank you

Comment: Yep, that would be the best way. No problem